# The category of models of a commutative algebraic theory.

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I'd like more information about the category of models $\mathcal{C}$ of a [commutative algebraic theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory). In particular:

1. Do finite coproducts necessarily exist, and if so, do they necessarily coincide with finite products?
2. Do all *small* coproducts necessarily exist?
3. Are there other properties that distinguish such categories $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: $\mathbf{Set}$ already is a counterexample to the existence of *arbitrary* coproducts -- in general, you only get *small* coproducts.

Comment: @Hurkyl, yeah I meant small. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The category of models for any (finitary, one-sorted) algebraic theory in $\mathbf{Set}$ is always complete and cocomplete. However, coproducts need not coincide with products even when the theory is commutative: consider the theory of $G$-sets for an abelian group $G$.

Comment: Is the condition "one-sorted" really necessary?

Comment: For the proof I had in mind, yes. But there are other proofs that generalise to the $\kappa$-ary, many-sorted case.

Comment: @user18921: I believe the [a variety of universal algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)) is a key point in history of the subject.